# Ubuntu installer won't recognize the full size of my partition

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, windows-10

I am relatively new to Linux and wanted to install it alongside Windows 10. I created a 51 GB partition with Windows Disk Managment for it and began the installation process for 18.04.03 LTS. When I got to the partition section it said that the only free partition space available was 16 GB. I would like more space than just 16 GB but I can't get it to recognize anymore space. If someone could please tell me what is going on and/or how to fix it that would be great.

Comment: The installer will created partition(s) from unpartitioned space, so either delete the 51G partion you just created, or seelct "something else" to designate the 51G partiion as your root (/).

Comment: @crisco-kid33 Boot from your LiveUSB wou would use for installation, but instead, open a terminal and run `parted print`, then copy the results, come back here, and click [edit], then paste the result into your question so we can see what your disk partitioning is.